# EF Core 6 - modelBuilder and mapper help (Friendship' cannot be added because it targets the keyless entity type 'Friendship')

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, ef-core-6.0

I am self teaching, so please excuse all ignorance here.

My goal is to make mappers and modelBuilders to make my life easier as I change things later on down the road. This seems like the correct thing to do.

But I am having all kinds of complications and as far as I know, I am going about my builders and mappers in all the wrong way, as well as my models. I have it working without the DefaultDataContext modelBuilder but I would like to improve it and make it better by establishing foreign keys and many relationships.

All the help is much appreciated. Just learning :)

**Error:**

> 'Friendship' cannot be added because it targets the keyless entity type 'Friendship'

I do not think that I need a key on my 'Friendship' model due to what it is used for. Friendship database holds entities called followee and follower. This creates me a composite table to make things easier I believe.

**Task**

Essentially in my endpoint I want to be able to...

1. Take in this user id.
2. Then look in the Friendships composite table and find the matching followee id columns and return all the follower id's.
3. Then with the follower id's, I want to use my Users table and get all the users info based on the follower id's.

**Code review**

`core/models/User`:

(*I removed the email and other items to avoid clutter*)

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an authenticated user account
/// </summary>
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Username of user
    /// </summary>
    [Sieve(CanFilter = true, CanSort = true)]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(300)")]
    public string? userName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; set; } = new List<UserRole>();

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Friendship> Friendship { get; set; } = new 
    List<Friendship>();
    }
```

`core/models/Dtos/UserDto`:

(*I removed the email and other items to avoid clutter*)

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an authenticated user account
/// </summary>
public class UserDto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// User id
    /// </summary>
    [Sieve(CanFilter = true, CanSort = true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Username
    /// </summary>
    [Sieve(CanFilter = true, CanSort = true)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// User roles
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<RoleDto> Roles { get; set; } = new List<RoleDto>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Associated role permissions
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<string> Permissions { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Associated friendships
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<string> Friendships { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

`core/models/Friendship`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an followee and follower friendship
/// </summary>
public class Friendship
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Id of followee
    /// </summary>
    [Sieve(CanFilter = true, CanSort = false)]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(300)")]
    public string Followee { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Id of follower
    /// </summary>
    [Sieve(CanFilter = true, CanSort = false)]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(300)")]
    public string? Follower { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// user relation
    /// </summary>
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual User? User { get; set; }
}
```

`core/models/Dtos/FriendshipFollowersDto`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Used to get the follwees followers
/// </summary>
public class FriendshipsFollowersDto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Follower id
    /// </summary>
    [Sieve(CanFilter = true, CanSort = true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Follower userName
    /// </summary>
    [Sieve(CanFilter = true, CanSort = true)]
    public string userName { get; set; }
}
```

`core/managers/FriendshipManager`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<FriendshipsFollowersDto>> List(string id)
{
    var results = DataContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id)
            ?.Friendship.Select(x => x.User).ToList();

    var result = DataContext.Users.Where(u => DataContext.Friendships.Any(f => f.Follower == u.Id)).ToList();

    return result.Select(Mapper.Map<FriendshipsFollowersDto>).ToList();
}
```

`core/data/DefaultDataContext`:

```
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>().HasNoKey();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>().HasOne(p => p.User).WithMany(t => t.Friendship).HasForeignKey(c => c.Followee);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.Friendship).WithOne().HasForeignKey(x => x.Followee);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

`core/profiles/AutoMapperMappingProfile`:

```
{
    CreateMap<FriendshipsFollowersDto, Friendship>().ReverseMap();
    CreateMap<FriendshipsFollowersDto, User>().ReverseMap();
}
```

Comment: Like the error suggests, you need Key columns to be declared so that EF knows how to track individual records in the db. Get your EF and data context working before you try to mix in mapping to DTOs, by doing too much at once you make it hard to identify the underlying issue

Comment: If you don't have a PK, then EF Core can't update / delete at all.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `Id` or some other arbitrary key column to the `Friendship` table so the EF can perform CRUD operations against individual records

- this by far is the *simplest* approach to M:N relationships in EF.

Against my better judgement I have added the `JsonIgnoreAttribute` so it will not be serialized:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an followee and follower friendship
/// </summary>
public class Friendship
{
    /// <summary>PK for Friendship record</summary>
    [Key]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get;set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Id of followee
    /// </summary>
    [Sieve(CanFilter = true, CanSort = false)]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(300)")]
    public string Followee { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Id of follower
    /// </summary>
    [Sieve(CanFilter = true, CanSort = false)]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(300)")]
    public string? Follower { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// user relation
    /// </summary>
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual User? User { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the `DbContext` configuration we do not need to explicitly define the key at all:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
                   .HasOne(p => p.User)
                   .WithMany(t => t.Friendship)
                   .HasForeignKey(c => c.Followee);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                   .HasMany(x => x.Friendship)
                   .WithOne()  
             .HasForeignKey(x => x.Follower);
```

It is also not necessary to specify the *same* relationship from the reciprocal point of view, so leave that out, but what you probably intended was to declare the `Follower` link...

The alternative and theoretically more correct implementation is to use a *composite key*, however composite keys have other operational conflicts with other toolsets and convention based SDKs, but you can configure this with fluent notation instead of changing the `Friendship` class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
                   .HasKey(f => new { f.Followee, f.Follower });

modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
                   .HasOne(p => p.User)
                   .WithMany(t => t.Friendship)
                   .HasForeignKey(c => c.Followee);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                   .HasMany(x => x.Friendship)
                   .WithOne()  
             .HasForeignKey(x => x.Follower);
```

Comment: This detail was much appreciated! I did have to change the Id from Int to String though cause upon update database, it was complaining that my User was a string and that the foreign key was not matching. Hopefully that was okay, it does seem fine now :)